# How to use the Time attribute in LWC table

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura, datatable, attribute

How do we format the **Time** in datatable like `HH:MM:SS` in the LWC data table.

In my datatable column type is defined as Time, expecting the date only format **HH:MM:SS**.

```
{ label: "Start Time", fieldName: "Program_Start_Time__c", type: **"time"** },
```

I went through the LWC data table Documentation:

Displays a date and time based on the locale using lightning-formatted-date-time.
Displaying Date and Time Using Type Attributes.

Type Attribute: day, era, hour, hour12, minute, month, second, timeZone, timeZoneName, weekday, year

```
typeAttributes: {
 day: 'numeric',
month: 'short',
year: 'numeric',
hour: '2-digit',
minute: '2-digit',
second: '2-digit',
hour12: true
}
```

For displaying only the Time for `type=time` i have tried the below,

```
{ label: "Start Time", fieldName: "Program_Start_Time__c", type: "time", typeAttributes: {
**hour: '2-digit',
minute: '2-digit',
second: '2-digit',
hour12: true**
} }
```

Unfortunately not getting the time for the field type Time. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be got to work by actually setting the type to "date" instead of "time" and using the type attributes you have. Let me know if that works for you.